# LSTM based Text Generation with Tensorflow : Problem With Generating Output Text

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to make an `LSTM` based text generator with `Tensorflow`. But I've some confusion regarding the sensible output generation. I'm trying to describe the whole situation concisely.

My Training Dataset: Bangla Song Lyrics (4000+ lyrics)

By taking two subsequent lines I've prepared a dataset with 30,000 samples.

- Minimum Sample Length: 25
- Maximum Sample Length: 120

I've tokenized each sample into characters and prepared a vocab dictionary that contains 181 unique vocabs.

I've prepared a **char_id** dictionary to encode each sample which contains ID 1 to 181. Each sample is encoded with these ID and 0 is used for padding.

Here is my model definition:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size+1,64),
    LSTM(512,return_sequences=True),
    LSTM(512,return_sequences=True),
    Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = [tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)],
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
])
```

Now here my embedding input dimension is **vocab_size+1** which is according to the documentation. And the last layer dimension is **vocab_size** since I want the model to predict a character with ID between 1 to 181.

Here is my train and target sample:

```
train = [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  3  4  5  9 10  3 11 12 13  7  4 14  9  3 15 16
  5 17  8 18  5 19 20  4  3 21 18  6 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]

target = [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  3  4  5  9 10  3 11 12 13  7  4 14  9  3 15 16  5
 17  8 18  5 19 20  4  3 21 18  6 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
```

You can see that I have shifted the target one index right to let the model predict the next character.

Now for generating the predicted output I use `np.argmax()` by passing the returned array from `model.prediction(tensor)`. The `np.argmax()` returns the position with the highest value and I'm taking it as an ID and converting it to the character. Am I doing it correctly?

Do I have to try `np.argmax(pred) + 1`? Since I have vocab set with ID 1 to 181. But predicted array has indices from 0 to 180.

Another problem is the validation loss becomes `nan` after the few steps in the first epoch and it remains `nan`. Setting clip value didn't solve the problem. I've seen that if the last layer dimension is set to `vocab_size+1` it fixes the problem. But this is also confusing.

Till now, I couldn't generate any text that makes sense. I'm trying hard to figure out what I am missing. I've described my current understanding too, so that, anyone can help me to understand my misunderstanding.